# Solving Keplerian two-body problem numerically?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, computational-physics

I'm trying to solve the two-body problem numerically, setting up G, m1 and m2 =1.0.
 The masses are placed at the positions -10 and 10 respectively along the x-axis and gave them both 0 on the y-axis. I am having some real issue with the initial conditions fitting for a keplerian orbit with a given eccentricity (e=0.9)!
Also how would the initial condition change for different mass ratios?

Comment: You can try different initial velocities and see what eccentricity they produce. Adjust them until you get 0.9. If you are doing a numerical simulation isn’t that more satisfying than having us work out a formula?

Comment: If you want to go through the pain of finding the right initial velocity that will yield a given eccentricity, this answer might help you get started: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/522208/how-can-i-calculate-the-speed-required-for-an-orbiting-planet-to-pass-through-a/522309#522309

Comment: I have used the vis-viva equation v = sqrt( GM * (2/r -1/a)) at apocentre but that yields a incorrect velocity. Is there no simple equation to calculate the initial velocitites?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we give the two masses initial velocities in the $\hat{y}$ and $-\hat{y}$ directions, perpendicular to their separation, we'll be starting at either periapsis or apoapsis.

The [*vis-viva* equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_mechanics#Velocity) for a binary system says that

$$v^2=G(m_1+m_2)\left(\frac{2}{r}-\frac{1}{a}\right)\tag1.$$

Here $r$ is the distance between the two masses, which is the magnitude of the separation vector

$$\mathbf{r}=\mathbf{r}_1-\mathbf{r}_2\tag2;$$

note that this is *not* the distance of either from their barycenter.

The speed $v$ is the magnitude of the *relative* velocity vector

$$\mathbf{v}=\frac{d\mathbf{r}}{dt}=\mathbf{v}_1-\mathbf{v}_2\tag3.$$

The semimajor axis $a$ is for the ellipse formed by $\mathbf{r}$, not the smaller ellipses formed by $\mathbf{r}_1$ or $\mathbf{r}_2$.

The ellipse formed by $\mathbf{r}$ has the form

$$r=\frac{a(1-e^2)}{1+e\cos\theta}\tag4$$

where $\theta=0$ at periapsis and $e$ is the eccentricity.

The value of $r$ at apoapsis is

$$r_a=a(1+e)\tag5.$$

So the relative speed at apoapsis is

$$\begin{align}
v_a&=\sqrt{G(m_1+m_2)\left(\frac{2}{r_a}-\frac{1}{a}\right)}\\
&=\sqrt{G(m_1+m_2)\left(\frac{2}{r_a}-\frac{1+e}{r_a}\right)}\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{G(m_1+m_2)}{r_a}(1-e)}\\
\end{align}\tag6.$$

Thus, given your initial data, we can find the initial *relative* speed.

To determine the initial speed of each mass, we use the fact that

$$\mathbf{r_1}=\frac{m_2}{m_1+m_2}\mathbf{r}\tag7$$

and

$$\mathbf{r_2}=-\frac{m_1}{m_1+m_2}\mathbf{r}\tag8$$

which follow from (2) plus the condition that the center of mass is at the origin:

$$\frac{m_1\mathbf{r}_1+m_2\mathbf{r}_2}{m_1+m_2}=0\tag9.$$

We thus have

$$\mathbf{v_1}=\frac{m_2}{m_1+m_2}\mathbf{v}\tag{10}$$

and

$$\mathbf{v_2}=-\frac{m_1}{m_1+m_2}\mathbf{v}\tag{11}$$

Putting in your numbers $G=m_1=m_2=1$, $r_a=(10)-(-10)=20$, and $e=9/10$, we find the initial speeds should be

$$v_1=v_2=\frac{1}{1+1}\sqrt{\frac{(1)(1+1)}{20}\left(1-\frac{9}{10}\right)}=\frac{1}{20}\tag{12}.$$

Trying this in *Mathematica* using

> data = NBodySimulation[
> "InverseSquare", {<|"Mass" -> 1, "Position" -> {10, 0},
> "Velocity" -> {0, 1/20}|>,
> <|"Mass" -> 1, "Position" -> {-10, 0}, "Velocity" -> {0, -1/20}|>},
> 400]

> ParametricPlot[Evaluate[data[All, "Position", t]], {t, 0, 400}]

one gets

[image]

As a check, the separation at periapsis should be

$$r_p=a(1-e)=r_a\frac{1-e}{1+e}=20\frac{1-\frac{9}{10}}{1+\frac{9}{10}}=\frac{20}{19}\approx 1.05\tag{13}$$

and it seems to be.

Comment: Thank you soo much G.Smith! 
This makes complete sense!

Comment: Hi, I have a doubt......if we calculate the velocity required for circular orbit by gravitational force = centrifugal we get the same velocity as that of an elliptical orbit with e = 0.5 so in that case what will happen

Comment: Hi, Can you run me through your calculation?

Comment: @Warrenmovic If you want to get Mitul’s attention, address him with @ like I here addressed you.

Comment: Thanks @G.Smith .

Comment: @MitulAgrawal , can you please run me though your calculation?

Comment: @Warrenmovic for circular orbit they revolve about origin.... Mv^2/10 = GM^2 /20^2 ......v^2 = GM/40 = 1/80......v = 1/2*sqrt(20)........which is same as elliptical orbit speed for e = 0.5

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/) to solve the numerical solution of this problem:

```
data  = NBodySimulation[
  "InverseSquare", {<|"Mass" -> 1, "Position" -> {0, 0}, 
    "Velocity" -> {0, .5}|>,
   <|"Mass" -> 1, "Position" -> {1, 1}, "Velocity" -> {0, -.5}|>}, 4]
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[data[All, "Position", t]], {t, 0, 4}]
```

[image]