# Two-body problem: equal mass keplerian orbit?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, computational-physics

Sorry to post a question on this again but I am still struggling putting two equal mass objects in a keplerian orbit. To summarise:

1) I have placed two bodies of masses 0.5 at +- 10 units on the x-axis so that the initial velocities will be in the +- y axis

2) Would like to set the bodies on a eccentric orbit of e=0.9 and integrate it numerically. However I need to initialise the velocities of each object and I cannot seem to calculate it.

3) I assume G=1.0

I have looked in a few books and the velocity of individual masses in the keplerian two body problem is not really discuss so I think I am missing something here.
Can someone please guide me through the calculation to obtain the velocity of each object?

Comment: This is the third time that you have asked the same question.

Comment: I am sorry about this but I feel that I am going round in circles. I really appreciated your help on my previous question but I have still not managed to figure it out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Solving Keplerian two-body problem numerically?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/533517/)