# How to calculate Earth's speed due to moon induced orbit?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics, solar-system

In https://stackoverflow.com/q/75297814/
the answer for the problem was that the earth like the moon had a speed due to the moon induced orbit. I don't understand how this was calculated? I have searched all over internet but not found an explanation.

Comment: Did "all over the internet" include "Barycenter"?

Comment: @JEB Yes, it did.

Comment: That Stack Overflow answer uses simple Euler integration to calculate the orbits. That doesn't work very well. There are many other integration techniques that give better results and which are more efficient, eg, Leapfrog, Verlet, various Runge-Kutta methods, etc.

Comment: Please see https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/533832/123208 for info on velocities in binary orbits.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume you are looking for the speed of the Earth in the rest frame of the center-of-mass/barycenter of the Earth-Moon system.

As per usual, in the center-of-mass frame, the total momentum of the Earth-Moon system vanishes. Thus, we have
$$Mv_{\text{Earth}}=mv_{\text{Moon}},$$
where $M,m$ are the masses of the Earth and Moon respectively. Thus, if you know the speed of the Moon, you can figure out the speed of the Earth, and vice-versa (given their masses).

Comment: That makes sense! So, if I understood this correctly, if we assume that the center of mass is in same place as earth (initially) then the earth has to be at rest. For that to happen the earth has to have the same momentum as the moon. Is it right?